# General Advice about When to Use Prop and When to use bool

Tags: coq

I am formalizing a grammar which is essentially one over boolean expressions. In coq, you can get boolean-like things in Prop or more explicitly in bool.

So for example, I could write:

```
true && true
```

Or

```
True /\ True
```

The problem is that in proofs (which is what I really care about) I can do a case analysis in domain bool, but in Prop this is not possible (since all members are not enumerable, I suppose). Giving up this tactic and similar rewriting tactics seems like a huge drawback even for very simple proofs.

In general, what situations would one choose Prop over bool for formalizing? I realize this is a broad question, but I feel like this is not addressed in the Coq manual sufficiently. I am interested in real world experience people have had going down both routes.

Comment: I suggest you post the exact same question on Coq's mailing list, coq-club :)

Comment: Software Foundations have some related material on this, see e.g. [here](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/Logic.html#lab186).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of different opinions on this. My personal take is that you are often better off not making this choice: it makes sense to have two versions of a property, one in `Prop`, the other one in `bool`.

Why would you want this? As you pointed out, booleans support case analysis in proofs and functions, which general propositions do not. However, `Prop` is more convenient to use in certain cases. Suppose you have a type `T` with finitely many values. We can write a procedure

```
all : (T -> bool) -> bool
```

that decides whether a boolean property `P : T -> bool` holds of all elements of `T`. Imagine that we know that `all P = true`, for some property `P`. We might want to use this fact to conclude that `P x = true` for some value `x`.  To do this, we need to prove a lemma about `all`:

```
allP : forall P : T -> bool,
         all P = true <-> (forall x : T, P x = true)
```

This lemma connects two different formulations of the same property: a boolean one and a propositional one. When reasoning about `all` in a proof, we can invoke `allP` to convert freely between the two. We can also have different conversion lemmas:

```
allPn : forall P,
          all P = false <-> (exists x, P x = false)
```

In fact, we are free to choose *any* Coq proposition whatsoever to relate to a boolean computation (as long, of course, as we can prove that the two are logically equivalent). For instance, if we would like to have a custom induction principle associated with a boolean property, we can look for an equivalent formulation as an inductively defined proposition.

The [Mathematical Components](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library is a good example of development that follows this style. Indeed, because it is so pervasive there, the library provides a special *view* mechanism for writing conversion lemmas like the one above and applying them. In plain Coq, we can also use the `rewrite` tactic to apply logical equivalences more conveniently.

Of course, there are many situations where it does not make sense to have two formulations of the same property. Sometimes, you are forced to use `Prop`, because the property you care about is undecidable. Sometimes, you might feel that you wouldn't gain anything by writing your property in `Prop`, and may keep it only as a boolean.

In addition to the [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/Logic.html#lab186) chapter linked above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554453/why-are-logical-connectives-and-booleans-separate-in-coq/31568076#31568076) discusses the difference between `bool` and `Prop` in more depth.

Comment: Indeed some people is wary of what they call "Boolean blindness", I am a fan of being boolean-blind and recovering my sight only when needed, in particular in the context of program verification. It should be noted that the core Math-Comp parts pertaining boolean reflection will be part of the upcoming Coq 8.7 release, so there is really little reason not to use them if your proof adapts well to this style.

Comment: Personally, I tend to work with `Prop` until a decision of one of the propositions is necessary, and then use `sumbool P (~P)` (which has notation `{P} + {~P}`).  Then if you have some calculation of `{P} + {~P}`, eliminating that object gives the true/false dichotomy, and you also get a direct proof of either `P` or `~P` (instead of having to apply a reflection lemma).

Comment: @DanielSchepler That is true, although the `reflect` predicate used in MathComp makes it much simpler to perform case analysis on a boolean reflecting a proposition `P` while obtaining proofs of `P` or `~ P` on each branch: it suffices to destruct the proof of `reflect P b`.

Comment: this is a great answer.