# Boolean equality of lists in Coq?

Tags: coq

I want to be able to compare two items of type "list" in Coq and get a boolean "true" or "false" for their equivalence.

Right now, I'm comparing the two lists this way:

```
Eval vm_compute in (list 1 = list 2).
```

I get a Prop of the form:

```
= nil
   :: (2 :: 3 :: nil)
      :: (2 :: nil)
         :: (3 :: nil) :: nil =
   nil
   :: (2 :: 3 :: nil)
      :: (2 :: nil)
         :: (3 :: nil) :: nil
 : Prop
```

Obviously list1 = list2, so how do I get it to just return true or false?

Comment: Have you made your own definition of `list`?  Usually it is a type constructor, such that `list nat` is the **type** of lists of numbers.  But you seem to be using it as a (value) constructor, creating a concrete list, so you must have cooked up something of your own, right?

Comment: Note that `=` returns a `Prop`, which is not the same thing as a boolean. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31568076/1633770) explains the issue in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Mathematical Components Library boolean equality operators](https://math-comp.github.io/math-comp/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.eqtype.html):

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

...

Eval vm_compute in list 1 == list 2
```

Comment: In the context of one of my proofs, I have ``H0 : (a1 == a2) = true``. How should I use ``a1`` or ``a2`` interchangeably in my proof? I mean how  I should change this hypothesis to something like ``a1=a2``. For example, how should I change  the goal like ``equalityfunction a1 b=true`` to ``equalityfunction a2 b=true``, based on the hypothesis.

Comment: @TomAnd., mathcomp indeed provides extremely good support for that, you would use for example `rewrite (eqP H0)`, `eqP` is the lemma that relates boolean equality with its propositional counterpart.

Comment: This works for me. I appreciate it. I wonder if you refer to a good resource to learn Mathcomp.

Comment: The math comp book is the main reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a boolean list equality function that takes as input a boolean equality over the elements automatically using Coq's commands:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List Coq.Bool.Bool.

Import Coq.Lists.List.ListNotations.

Scheme Equality for list.
```

This prints:

```
list_beq is defined
list_eq_dec is defined
```

where `list_beq` is a boolean equality function on lists that takes as first parameter a comparison function for the lists elements and then two lists:

```
Print list_beq.
```

Gives

```
list_beq = 
fun (A : Type) (eq_A : A -> A -> bool) =>
fix list_eqrec (X Y : list A) {struct X} : bool :=
  match X with
  | [] => match Y with
          | [] => true
          | _ :: _ => false
          end
  | x :: x0 => match Y with
               | [] => false
               | x1 :: x2 => eq_A x x1 && list_eqrec x0 x2
               end
  end
     : forall A : Type, (A -> A -> bool) -> list A -> list A -> bool
```

and

```
Check list_eq_dec
```

gives

```
list_eq_dec
     : forall (A : Type) (eq_A : A -> A -> bool),
       (forall x y : A, eq_A x y = true -> x = y) ->
       (forall x y : A, x = y -> eq_A x y = true) -> forall x y : list A, {x =  y} + {x <> y}
```

showing that list equality is decidable if the underlying types equality is agrees with leibniz equality.

Comment: Note that you can get Coq to generate most of this for you by writing `Scheme Equality for list.`

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about `Scheme Equality`. I will update my answer accordingly.