# Understanding Coq through a simple theorem proof

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I'm very new to Coq, and now I'm stuck trying to understand how Coq "reasons" with a simple theorem:

```
Theorem andb_true_elim2 : forall b c : bool,
  andb b c = true -> c = true.
```

I supposed that the proof would be just:

```
Proof.
  intros b c.
  destruct c.
    - destruct b.
     + reflexivity.
     + reflexivity.
    - destruct b.
     + reflexivity.
     + reflexivity.
  Qed.
```

But it fails with:

```
In environtment
H: true && false = true
Unable to unify "true" with "false"
```

The subgoal failing is the third `reflexivity`, where `c` is `false` and `b` is `true`:

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
true && false = true -> false = true
```

Why is that? Wasn't it equivalent to an implication?

```
true && (false = true) -> (false = true)
true && false -> false
false -> false
true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues with this proof. First, you misunderstood what Coq wanted; the actual goal was the following:

```
((true && false) = true) -> (false = true)
```

This does *not* follow by reflexivity, as the conclusion of this formula, `false = true`, is an equality between two syntactically different expressions.

Second, Coq does not simplify the operators `->` and `=` in the manner you described.  Coq's theory allows automatic simplification in a few select expressions, such as those defined by case analysis.  For instance, `&&` is syntactic sugar for the `andb` function, which is defined in the standard library as follows:

```
Definition andb b c :=
  if b then c else false.
```

When Coq sees an expression such as `false && true`, it expands it to the equivalent `if false then true else false`, which in turn simplifies to the else branch `true`.  You can test this by calling the `simpl` tactic on the problematic branch.

The `->` and `=` operators, on the other hand, are defined differently: the first one is a primitive in the logic, whereas the other one is a so-called inductive proposition.  Neither of those can be automatically simplified in Coq, because they express concepts that are in general not computable: for instance, we can use `=` to express the equality of two functions `f` and `g` that take infinitely many natural numbers as inputs.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554453/why-are-logical-connectives-and-booleans-separate-in-coq/31568076) discusses this difference in more detail.

If you want, you can state your theorem in a purely computable way with alternate definitions of implication and equality:

```
Definition negb b := if b then false else true.

Definition eqb b c := if b then c else negb c.

Definition implb b c := if b then c else true.

Lemma test : forall b c, (implb (eqb (andb b c) true) (eqb c true))
                         = true.
Proof. intros [] []; reflexivity. Qed.
```

However, a statement like this is generally harder to use in Coq.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer @Arthur.

Then I don't understand why the second `reflexivity` succeeds. There, `c` is `true` and `b` is `false`, so the goal is:

`((false && true) = true) -> (true = true)`

which is in turn:

`(false = true) -> (true = true)`.

 In this case I also have two syntatically different expressions (at the left of `->`). Isn't it?

Comment: @WaitingforDev... What matters for reflexivity is the goal's conclusion, that is, the right-most equation.  Since it says `true = true`, reflexivity works.

Comment: I see... what I think I don't get is how to prove something in the case of `c` being `false` when what I have to prove is `c` being `true` for the hypothesis...

Comment: @WaitingforDev... Indeed, you have to prove something contradictory in that case.  But you have a contradictory hypothesis in your context at that point, which allows you to conclude.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that :)