# Better theory of vectors in Coq?

Tags: coq

Coq's `Vector` doesn't have the plethora of theorems that `List` has. How do people use `Vector` "in the wild"? Does everyone have their own development? What are some well known "standard libraries" of Coq?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42302300/2747511) is strongly related.

Comment: Indeed, I had seen that. That asks how to develop a good theory of vectors, though. I am looking for stuff that exists :)

Comment: When I see "What is the best or most common practice for someone who doesn't want to roll their own library? " I understand it as "I am looking for stuff that exists". So it seems to me that your question is duplicate.

Comment: Depends on your requirements, but math-comp's tuple is a quite complete theory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which vector library to use in coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42302300/which-vector-library-to-use-in-coq)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend CoLoR http://color.inria.fr/
(there is an OPAM package `coq-color`)