# indexed by a type vs containing a type in idris

Tags: types, records, dependent-type, idris, phantom-types

I'm currently going through the [Type-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) book.

I have two questions relating to the design of the example data store in Chapter 6.  The data store is a command line application that allows the user to set what kind of data is stored in it, and then add new data.

Here are the relevant parts of the code (simplified slightly).  You can see the [full code](https://github.com/cdepillabout/TypeDD-Samples/blob/91c199f2fa8ca94369cda5709215ad30ee813203/Chapter6/MyDataStore.idr) on Github:

```
module Main

import Data.Vect

infixr 4 .+.

-- This datatype is to define what sorts of data can be contained in the data store.
data Schema
  = SString
  | SInt
  | (.+.) Schema Schema

-- This is a type-level function that translates a Schema to an actual type.
SchemaType : Schema -> Type
SchemaType SString = String
SchemaType SInt = Int
SchemaType (x .+. y) = (SchemaType x, SchemaType y)

-- This is the data store.  It can potentially be storing any sort of schema.
record DataStore where
       constructor MkData
       schema : Schema
       size : Nat
       items : Vect size (SchemaType schema)

-- This adds new data to the datastore, making sure that the new data is
-- the same type that the DataStore holds.
addToStore
  : (dataStore : DataStore) -> SchemaType (schema dataStore) -> DataStore
addToStore (MkData schema' size' store') newitem =
  MkData schema' _ (addToData store')
  where
    addToData
      : Vect size' (SchemaType schema') -> Vect (size' + 1) (SchemaType schema')
    addToData xs = xs ++ [newitem]

-- These are commands the user can use on the command line.  They are able
-- to change the schema, and add new data.
data Command : Schema -> Type where
  SetSchema : (newSchema : Schema) -> Command schema
  Add : SchemaType schema -> Command schema

-- Given a Schema, this parses input from the user into a Command.
parse : (schema : Schema) -> String -> Maybe (Command schema)

-- This is the main workhorse of the application.  It parses user
-- input, turns it into a command, then evaluates the command and 
-- returns an updated DataStore.
processInput
  : (dataStore : DataStore) -> String -> Maybe (String, DataStore)
processInput dataStore@(MkData schema' size' items') input =
  case parse schema' input of
    Nothing => Just ("Invalid command\n", dataStore)
    Just (SetSchema newSchema) =>
      Just ("updated schema and reset datastore\n", MkData newSchema _ [])
    Just (Add item) =>
      let newStore = addToStore (MkData schema' size' items') item
      in Just ("ID " ++ show (size dataStore) ++ "\n", newStore)

-- This kicks off processInput with an empty datastore and a simple Schema
-- of SString.
main : IO ()
main = replWith (MkData SString _ []) "Command: " processInput
```

This makes sense and is easy to use, but one thing bugged me about the design.  *Why does the `DataStore` contain a `Schema` instead of being indexed by one*?

Because the `DataStore` is not indexed by a `Schema`, we could have written an incorrect `addToStore` function like this:

```
addToStore
  : (dataStore : DataStore) -> SchemaType (schema dataStore) -> DataStore
addToStore _ newitem =
  MkData SInt _ []
```

Here is what I would imagine more type safe code would look like.  You can see the [full code](https://github.com/cdepillabout/TypeDD-Samples/blob/91c199f2fa8ca94369cda5709215ad30ee813203/Chapter6/MyDataStore2.idr) on Github:

```
module Main

import Data.Vect

infixr 4 .+.

data Schema
  = SString
 | SInt
 | (.+.) Schema Schema

SchemaType : Schema -> Type
SchemaType SString = String
SchemaType SInt = Int
SchemaType (x .+. y) = (SchemaType x, SchemaType y)

record DataStore (schema : Schema) where
       constructor MkData
       size : Nat
       items : Vect size (SchemaType schema)

addToStore
  : (dataStore : DataStore schema) ->
    SchemaType schema ->
    DataStore schema
addToStore {schema} (MkData size' store') newitem =
  MkData _ (addToData store')
  where
    addToData
      : Vect size' (SchemaType schema) -> Vect (size' + 1) (SchemaType schema)
    addToData xs = xs ++ [newitem]

data Command : Schema -> Type where
  SetSchema : (newSchema : Schema) -> Command schema
  Add : SchemaType schema -> Command schema

parse : (schema : Schema) -> String -> Maybe (Command schema)

processInput
  : (schema : Schema ** DataStore schema) ->
    String ->
    Maybe (String, (newschema ** DataStore newschema))
processInput (schema ** (MkData size' items')) input =
  case parse schema input of
    Nothing => Just ("Invalid command\n", (_ ** MkData size' items'))
    Just (SetSchema newSchema) =>
      Just ("updated schema and reset datastore\n", (newSchema ** MkData _ []))
    Just (Add item) =>
      let newStore = addToStore (MkData size' items') item
          msg = "ID " ++ show (size newStore) ++ "\n"
      in Just (msg, (schema ** newStore))

main : IO ()
main = replWith (SString ** MkData _ []) "Command: " processInput
```

---

Here are my two questions:

1. Why didn't the book use the more type-safe version of the `DataStore` type (the one indexed by the `Schema`)?  Is there something that is gained by using the less type-safe version (the one that just contains a `Schema`)?
2. What is the theoretical difference of a type being indexed by another type vs containing another type?  Does this difference change depending on what language you are working on?

   For instance, I imagine there might not be a big difference in Idris, but there is quite a big difference in Haskell. (Right...?)

   I just started playing around with Idris (and I am not particularly well-versed with the use of singletons or GADTs in Haskell), so I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.  If you could point me to any papers talking about this, I'd be very interested.

Comment: @Shersh and the OP: The author actually made exactly this transition  later in the book (see sect. 10.3.2). Here is the [code from the book](https://github.com/edwinb/TypeDD-Samples/blob/a5c08a13e6a6ec804171526aca10aae946588323/Chapter10/DataStore.idr#L17)

Comment: @AntonTrunov This proves that this transformation is better. Maybe the first one was chosen for simlicity.

Comment: @Shersh Hmm, I think it mostly is a matter of taste. I, personally, would prefer a simpler datatype with several lemmas about its use. This way you can write your code and later prove some properties about it. Like you can use lists, write your programs ML- (or Haskell-) style, and later prove something about them, or you can use such notorious datatype as vector, in which case you sometimes can't even state properties about its values (I mean not using the heterogeneous equality, a.k.a. John Major Equality). See, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159566/2747511).

Comment: @AntonTrunov the book does use the transformation later in the book, but it notes, "Rather than storing the schema as a field in the record, here you parameterize the record by the data’s schema because you don’t intend to allow the schema to be updated." (section 10.3.2) I don't understand this comment.  In the code I posted above, the store is being parameterized by the schema, but it is still allowed to change by using dependent pairs.

Comment: I'm still interested in what the theoretical relationship is between having a data constructor "contain" a value, verse having a data type be parameterized by a value (type?).  Also, how it differs in dependently-typed languages (Idris) verses non-dependently-type languages (Haskell).

Comment: @illabout The comment means that e.g. `addToStore` cannot change the schema of the output datastore. To change the schema you need to use some *external* mechanism, e.g. dependent pairs, which makes your intention to change the schema explicit and this was not the case with the previous version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, this was pedantry.  Early on, a dependent record is used so that dealing with type indexes is not required.  Later, a indexed type is used in order to restrict (and make easier to find via proof-search) valid implementations.